# Number compliment of base 10 integer in c++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

We have given a number and we have to flip its 0's and 1's in its binary form and after flipping it we have to written resultant decimal number of that flipped binary number .

For Example - Input: n = 5
Output: 2
Reason-  5 is "101" in binary, with complement "010" in binary, which is 2 in base-10.

My try -

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  int ans=0;
  int a2ns=0;
  int finalans=0;
  int k=0;
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  while(n!=0){
    int bit = n&1;
    ans = bit*pow(10,i)+ans;
    i++;
    n=n>>1;
  }
  cout<<ans<<endl;
  while(ans!=0){
    int digit = ans&1;
    if(digit==0){
      digit =1;
    }
    else{
      digit =0;
    }
    a2ns = digit*pow(10,i)+a2ns;
    j++;
    ans = ans>>1;
  }
  cout<<a2ns<<endl;  
  while(a2ns!=0){
    int digit1 = a2ns%10;
    if(digit1==1){
      finalans = finalans + pow(2,k);
    }
    a2ns=a2ns/10;
    k++;
  }
  cout<<finalans;
}
```

> My Output-
> 235
> 11101011
> 1199999995
> 768

> Expected Output-
> 235
> 11101011
> 00010100
> 20

My in my case error is coming while flipping the binary number from 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 , this part of my answer is having error while rest is correct . So please anyone can correct me where am i wrong in this code.

Comment: integers are stored as binary. There is nothing really to convert, binary and decimal are just different representations of the same numbers. In any case `pow` is not to be used with integers.

Comment: why is binary representation of `5` not `0000101` or `00000000101` ?

Comment: Adding your number to its bit-flipped value will result in a power of 2 minus 1. That power will be the log (base 2) of your original number. You can compute that quite easily, and then all you need to do is a subtraction.

Comment: Can the input number be negative ?

Comment: @moldnilo requires some shifts too, because they seem to use the convention that `5` is `101` while (i guess)  `2` would be just `1`. Though still simpler that way then the current code

Comment: Can you confirm if your program is only supposed to receive inputs between 0 and 255? Or maybe it's supposed to flip bits up to the most significant 1 bit? More example input, please.

Comment: Bit flipping 235 to `10100` is as valid as bit flipping 235 to `11111111 11111111 11111111 00010100`, depending on your use case.

Comment: or use  `std::bitset`

Comment: @Damienn range is  0 <= n < 10^9

Comment: @paddy can you elaborate that?

Comment: @molbdnilo i know ~ exists but i was getting wrong answer by that so i didn't do by that

Comment: The main problem is you are trying to avoid flipping zeroes to the left of the most significant bit. The simplest mathematical way is to find the position of the bit, then do a subtraction. Or, you can just [use strings](https://godbolt.org/z/Waascd4fa) which is less cognitive load for a beginner.

Comment: @JohnFilleau So exactly how can i prevent flipping 235 to 11111111 11111111 11111111 00010100 but to 00000000 00000000 00000000 00010100 only ?

Comment: @paddy ok will try by that

Comment: @HarshvardhanSingh give someone a pen and paper and describe to them the task. Don't think about code. How would you do this by hand? Figure that out, break up the steps, and _then_ revisit the program.

Comment: log base-2 of 235 is 7. Using that value, `(1 << (7+1)) - 1` gives you 255. Using that value, `255 - 235` is 20. Think about what that math is actually doing. If you know how to add numbers together in binary, you'll see what's going on.

Comment: What the deuce? Use ~ on the integral type to flip the bits, and & on an appropriate number consisting of 1...1 in binary to fit the result to the desired width.

Answer (score 1):

You can write simply this, assuming that T is an unsigned type

```cpp
template< typename T >
T flip( T number ) {
#ifdef __cpp_lib_int_pow2
    int numbits = std::bit_width<T>(number);
#else
    int numbits = 0;
    T tmp = number;
    while ( tmp != 0 ) { tmp/=2; numbits++; }
#endif
    T mask = ~(T(-1) << numbits);
    number = ~number & mask;
    return number;
}
```

`std::bit_width<T>()` is a C++20 feature so the macro `__cpp_lib_int_pow2` tests for its existence.

Running a test

```cpp
void test() {
    for ( T j=0; j<10; ++j ) {
        std::cout << "value:" << j << " bin:" << binary(j) 
                  << " flip:" << binary(flip(j)) << std::endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    test<uint32_t>();
}
```

Produces

```
value:0 bin:0 flip:0
value:1 bin:1 flip:0
value:2 bin:10 flip:1
value:3 bin:11 flip:0
value:4 bin:100 flip:11
value:5 bin:101 flip:10
value:6 bin:110 flip:1
value:7 bin:111 flip:0
value:8 bin:1000 flip:111
value:9 bin:1001 flip:110
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Pxjn3cr6o

Comment: Sorry for not upvoting this sooner. It's exactly as I had written in my later comment. The only thing I don't like is the tautologous `tmp != 0` but that's largely opinion-based.

Comment: @Bathsheba I had to Google `tautologous` :)  Thanks!